# postgresql to read complete data as one single json

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `names` with two columns `id` and `name`. I want to read the whole data as one json object as

```
{ "id1Value": "name1", "id2Value": "name2" }
```

Table name is **names**: columns are `id` and `name`

I want to use any of json functions of postgres to get data in this format

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d05e63267224cd76bc2a474bbc3e20c1)

```
SELECT json_object_agg(id, name) FROM names
```

[Postgres JSON aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

`json_object_agg` aggregates the data of two columns in that way you expect

**Sample**:

```
| id |    name |
|----|---------|
|  1 |     Alf |
|  2 |   Bruce |
|  3 | Charlie |
```

**Result**

```
{ "1" : "Alf", "2" : "Bruce", "3" : "Charlie" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for [`jsonb_object_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select jsonb_object_agg(id::text, name)
from names;
```

With the following test data:

```
create table names (id integer, name text);
insert into names values (1, 'Arthur'), (2, 'Zaphod'), (3, 'Marvin');
```

The query returns:

```
jsonb_object_agg                             
---------------------------------------------
{"1": "Arthur", "2": "Zaphod", "3": "Marvin"}
```